# Cannot deserialize xml string with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0, json.net, json-deserialization

Hi I am passing an xml as string

```
<AbcDto xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Abc">
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Description>sample string 4</Description>
  <Name>sample string 3</Name>
  <PolicyId>c17f5b9f-c9bf-4a3a-b09b-f44ec84b0d00</PolicyId>
  <Status>Active</Status>
  <TimeZoneId>USCentral</TimeZoneId>
</AbcDto>
```

When I am trying creating Custom Model Binder for Web Api

```
   public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var jsonObject = (JObject) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                var jsonPropertyNames = jsonObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

The json string passing as an parameter to the below method is an xml as string
I am facing exception at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Exception Details:
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting an error because [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) expects JSON input, not XML.  If you want to handle XML with a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), you'll need to convert the XML to JSON first.  The [`JsonConvert`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) class has a [`SerializeXmlNode()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode.htm) method for this purpose.

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        <AbcDto xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Abc"">
          <Id>2</Id>
          <Description>sample string 4</Description>
          <Name>sample string 3</Name>
          <PolicyId>c17f5b9f-c9bf-4a3a-b09b-f44ec84b0d00</PolicyId>
          <Status>Active</Status>
          <TimeZoneId>USCentral</TimeZoneId>
        </AbcDto>";

        // If the json string contains XML, convert it to JSON
        if (json.TrimStart().StartsWith("<"))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(json);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.None, true);
        }

        // Now you can load the JSON into a JObject
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var jsonPropertyNames = jsonObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        foreach (string name in jsonPropertyNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@xmlns:i
@xmlns
Id
Description
Name
PolicyId
Status
TimeZoneId
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply.

Comment: Bu the issue I am facing is I can  send either a Json Object or XML.The single method needs to handle both scenarios.

Comment: Ah.  Well you never mentioned that in your question.  Fortunately, that is simple enough to solve; just add a check to detect whether the string is XML.  If it is, convert it to JSON.  If not, parse it as usual.  I've updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry for that. i will try the solution.Thanks for the response.