# Read an XML file, change it and save it as new formatted XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which has been exported from Orchard CMS, what I need to now do is convert the nodes within the XML file to a new structure so that I can import the file in to Umbraco.

How do I go about doing this? I'm thinking I could write some c# .net to read the XML file and then make the changes I need and then same it as a new file.

Example of a what I am trying to do is:

Exported file:

```
<BlogPost Id="/alias=The Blog\/2012\/09\/10\/on-starters-orders" Status="Published">
  <TextField.Excerpt />
  <TaxonomyField.Categories Terms="" />
  <TaxonomyField.Tags Terms="" />
  <BodyPart Text="MAIN CONTENT OF THE BLOG POST"
  />
  <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=Owain" Container="/alias=blog" CreatedUtc="2012-09-10T13:27:00Z" PublishedUtc="2012-09-25T08:57:25Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-09-25T08:56:15Z" />
  <AutoroutePart Alias="The Blog/2012/09/10/on-starters-orders" UseCustomPattern="false" />
  <TitlePart Title="On starters orders....." />
  <CommentsPart CommentsShown="true" CommentsActive="true" ThreadedComments="false" />
  <TagsPart Tags="" />
</BlogPost>
```

What I need to convert it to is:

```
 <posts>
    <post id="1" date-created="2012-09-25T08:57:25Z" date-modified="2012-09-25T08:56:15Z" approved="true" post-url="on-starters-orders" type="normal" hasexcerpt="false" views="0" is-published="True">
      <title type="text"><![CDATA[On starters orders.....]]></title>
      <content type="text"><![CDATA[MAIN CONTENT OF THE BLOG POST]]>
 </content>
  <post-name type="text"><![CDATA[On starters orders.....]]></post-name>
   <categories>
        <category ref="1018" />
      </categories>
       <tags>
        <tag ref="training" />
      </tags>
       <comments>
        <comment id="35" date-created="2006-09-05T11:36:50" date-modified="2006-09-05T11:36:50" approved="false" user-name="Phil Haack" user-url="http://haacked.com">
          <title type="text"><![CDATA[re: CS Dev Guide: Send Emails]]></title>
          <content type="text"><![CDATA[Another test comment.]]></content>
        </comment>
      </comments>
      <authors>
        <author ref="Owain" />
      </authors>
    </post>
```

Looking for suggestion on the best way to do this as I have 150+ posts to convert and don't fancy doing it manually.

Comment: Its definitely possible to do. There are plenty of xml readers. One example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005211/cannot-deserialize-xml-string-with-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-deserializeobject

Comment: Use [`xsd.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to define classes for your old and new XML, then use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the old XML, write c# code to map between the two, then use `XmlSerializer` again to write the new classes.

Comment: Or, use Linq-to-XML to [modify your XML in memory directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387084.aspx).

Comment: You could also define an `XSL` transformation to turn one to the other, which can be kind of fun.  But if you haven't done that before and need a quick solution, I'd use Linq-to-XML, as @dbc suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone - Im going to look at the Linq option as I haven't used Linq much and it will be a good way to learn. I'll post my solution once I have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT transformation which has a lot of options to do what you are looking for. XSLT can output in xml.